# Samsung Galaxy 7" (GT-P6210) USB debugging is not detecting in Linux?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-tab, 3.0-honeycomb, 3.2-honeycomb

I am using ubuntu Linux 10.04 Pc in that my **Samsung Galaxy 7"** (GT-P6210) **homeycomb 3.2** is not detecting for development its showing in eclipse as

`DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring ????????????`  in **console**

and in **device tab** its showing ?????????????.

Except this **7' GT-P6210** Samsung tablet all other Samsung devices are showing fine.

When I switch off the tablet and connected to the USB its showing the number and online as status. 
List of devices attached 
4641199B0F8488AE    device

why? whats the problem any solution.

**NOTE:**
I already Added 51-android.rules

```
Samsung 04E8
```

and also I enabled the **USB debugging** mode.

Its working fine in **Mac**.

I found that only its not detecting in updated ADT r16, except all other ADT version device is detecting very fine.

any idea?

Answer (score 10):

When `adb` shows devices as `????????????` it's usually a permission problem and the usb device file. Your `udev` rules doesn't seem right. Make sure that you have udev configured to something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

Where `04e8` is Samsung's USB Vendor ID.

Under Linux there is also an `adb_usb.ini` from the SDK where you have to add the vendor IDs:

`~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x17ef
0x1949
```

Comment: Oh that's funny, add vendor IDs when it says "DO NOT EDIT" :)

Comment: You can safely ignore this warning. Just manually add the vendor IDs. More on `android update adb` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html).

Comment: Wasn't saying that you are wrong, I just found that amusing :) But thanks for clarifying it

Comment: @Flow I just want know why when I switch off the tablet and connected to the USB its showing the number and online as status. adb devices List of devices attached 4641199B0F8488AE device