# Device shows up as ????? in ADB

Tags: rooting, adb, amazon-kindle-fire

I am running Ubuntu on my computer and I plugged in my tablet to flash TWRP to it. I enter `adb devices` and here is the output:

```
juniorRubyist@juniorRubyist-iMac:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions

...
```

Why is it doing this. I have a Kindle Fire 1st Generation, it says that it will ask to authorize ADB, but it will not. It has ADB enabled (I think) and everything.

Comment: *It has ADB enabled (I think)* How solid?

Comment: @SarpSTA I read on Amazon that it is enabled by default.

Comment: Can you check manually?

Comment: Is there a way to disable and renable ADB? Sometimes I have to do that and unplug/replug in the device to get the authorization dialog to come up.

Comment: It's because of the USB device permissions being insufficient. Try adding a [udev rule](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/37085/981) and see if that allows you to communicate with it. You may also need to add some lines to the [android_usb.ini](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/17581/981), if you have one. Running the ADB server on your PC as root is also an option, but not considered ideal.

Comment: Please see [How do I get my device detected by ADB on Linux?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/16575) – and take care for the `adb_usb.ini` part. I had the same issue until then (also on Ubuntu). Also try to unplug/replug the cable (helped with some other devices here).

Comment: @Izzy That article was perfect. I would like to give you the answered question.

Comment: @juniorRubyist So it solved your issue? Shall we then mark your question as "duplicate" to that, redirecting there for the answer? // Yeah, unfortunately you can neither upvote nor accept the answer there, not enough rep yet. But you can upvote it later when you've collected some :)

Comment: @Izzy Ok, that would be fine with me. I could upvote it later, plus, I only have 1 rep and this isn't my main SE.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same for me on Ubuntu. These commands should solve it:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb devices
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. I already got it fixed.